# How to evaluate multiple conditions at once, but detect which control failed and display error message?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently working on a Winforms application which contains various ways of validating user input, all of which have to be met otherwise they are prompted with an `ErrorProvider` icon next to the control that failed. This is my  `saveForm` function. This is also triggered from a `Click event`

My issue is that I need to check all of my conditions at the same time rather than one after another, as every time the press save they are the displayed with a new error until the validation is met.

I know I can obviously use the `||` operator or `&&` but I need to appropriately display the corresponding message using the `SetError` method. So how would I be able to have the validation conditions evaluated at the same time but detect which control failed and display the unique message for that control.

`SaveForm()` method:

```
try
{
    var errorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>() { epEmail, epAlternative, epMobile, epTown, epLandline, epHouseName, epForeName, epSurname, epPostcode, epCountry, epHouseName, epLocality, epCounty };

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_ForeName.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_SurName.Text))
    {
        epBothNames.SetError(txt_SurName, "Error:"); 
        epBothNames.SetError(txt_ForeName, "Error:");
        return false;
    }

    if (cmb_Title.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {   
        epTitle.SetError(cmb_Title, "Title"); 
        return false; 
    }

    if (cmb_PrefConTime.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {   
        epPrefConTime.SetError(cmb_PrefConTime, "Error in: prefered contact time feild");
        return false; 
    }

    if (!isPhoneNumber())
    {   
        epPrefConNumber.SetError(cmb_PrefConNumber, "Error");
        return false; 
    }

    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls) 
    {
        if(c is SpellBox || c is TextBox)
        {
            if (!errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0))
            { 
                return false; 
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())+ "Error has occurred, Please cancel and try again!");
}

return true;
```

Comment: It is hard to tell from just this bit of code, but I think if you remove the return statements in the if statements, and return all of the messages at the end of the method, you can set your fields with errors and return the messages.

Comment: Why don't you create an integer number and set each individual bit with some particular result/control? I mean, if you must have 20 controls set, you may consider one bit to each one, OR it with 1 and at the end check if this number is 2 ^20 (all bits are on). At the same time, you may create another array of error messages, and link each error position with the same bit position of above, presenting the error messages in a While-Loop that checks each bit of the integer-var final result.

Comment: @DavidBS I've edited my code a tad. I have a loop to check all of the errors before they can save the data. I have all of my errorProviders stored in a List. would you be able to provide an example of how I would loink the message and display the correct error message ?

Comment: @RudyTheHunter is right. All you have to do is to let this code run to the end. Instead of `return` do `hasErrors = true`. In the end, `if (!hasErrors) Save()`. Don't even go about `|| and &&`. It has nothing to do with it

Comment: In this way you made if preferable really follow the RudyTheHunter advise - just take off the RETURN and set a boolean var - like T.S. advises.

Comment: Thank you guys all resolved with a mixture of your comments thanks a lot. @RudyTheHunter Post your answer will upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from just this bit of code, but I think if you remove the return statements in the if statements, and return all of the messages at the end of the method, you can set your fields with errors and return the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer works perfectly, but i havent got enough rep to upvote so will do as soon as i do

Comment: You can select it as the answer.